# HTML form with PHP returns empty variables

Tags: php, forms

I try to send couple values from html form into database but variables are empty.
If I print variables in php area like `echo $ad1_uid;` I get the value.
After sending - all values are empty:

```
author_uid=&state=complete&mail=&user_uid=
```

Where could be a reason?

```
<form action="" method="get">


  <input type="hidden" value="<?php ''.$ad1_uid; ?>" name="author_uid">
  <input type="hidden" value="complete" name="state">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php ''.$user->mail; ?>" name="mail"> 
  <button name="user_uid" type="submit" value="<?php ''.$user->uid; ?>">Zapisuje się</button>
</form>    

<?php
}

$wyslany_user_uid = $_GET['user_uid'];
$wyslany_author_uid = $_GET['author_uid'];
$wyslany_mail = $_GET['mail']; 
$wyslany_state = $_GET['state']; 
var_dump($wyslany_mail);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `krajeto_demo`.`registration1`
        (user_uid, author_uid, mail, state ) VALUES (
        '" . $wyslany_user_uid . "', '" . $wyslany_author_uid. "', '" . $wyslany_mail . "','" . $wyslany_state . "' 
        ");




?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

To output the value of `$ad1_uid` in the form, try this instead:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $ad1_uid; ?>" name="author_uid">
```

Or this if your [setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) don't

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ad1_uid; ?>" name="author_uid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PHP` is not set to echo data into the form.

I've fixed those and added a debug clause to run. Just set to false once you've ran it to output data.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ad1_uid; ?>" name="author_uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="complete" name="state">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user->mail; ?>" name="mail"> 
    <button name="user_uid" type="submit" value="<?php echo $user->uid; ?>">Zapisuje się</button>
</form>

<?php
}

$debug = true;
if ($debug === true)
{
    echo '<hr />
    <h4>Debug Area</h4>
    <pre>';

    print_r(array($_GET, $_POST));

    echo '</pre>
    <hr />';
}
$wyslany_user_uid       = $_GET['user_uid'];
$wyslany_author_uid     = $_GET['author_uid'];
$wyslany_mail           = $_GET['mail']; 
$wyslany_state          = $_GET['state']; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `krajeto_demo`.`registration1` (user_uid, author_uid, mail, state ) VALUES (
    '" . $wyslany_user_uid . "', '" . $wyslany_author_uid. "', '" . $wyslany_mail . "','" . $wyslany_state . "' 
    ");
```

Try that and let me know what is echo'd to you.